# How find the equaition $x^2\sin{\dfrac{1}{x}}=2x-501$ root

Tags: algebra-precalculus, transcendental-equations

find the equation approximate solution , such the root of

> $$x^2\sin{\dfrac{1}{x}}=2x-501$$ to an accuracy of $ 0.001$
>
> I think this problem  use this
> $$\sin{x}\approx x-\dfrac{1}{6}x^3$$
> then
> $$x^2(\dfrac{1}{x}-\dfrac{1}{6x^3})\approx 2x-501$$
> $$\Longrightarrow x-\dfrac{1}{6x}\approx 2x-501$$
> $$x+\dfrac{1}{6x}\approx 501$$

so I guess $$x\approx 501$$

because when $$x=501,\dfrac{1}{6x}\approx \dfrac{1}{3000}\approx 0.0003$$

My methods is true? Have you other methods? Thank you

> it is said idea use
> $$\sin{y}=y-\dfrac{\sin{(\theta y)}}{2}y^2,0<\theta<1\cdots\cdots(1)$$
> But this is Taylor formula? and How prove $(1)$ it？

Comment: The  Maple [fsolve](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=fsolve) command does the job: $$fsolve(x^2*sin(1/x) = 2*x-501) $$ outputs $500.9996673 $.

Comment: Do you know Newton's iteration method?

Answer (score 3):

Let $x = 1/t$ and multiply by $t$.  The equation becomes
$$ \dfrac{\sin(t)}{t} = 2 - 501 t$$
Assuming you're looking for real solutions, $-1 < \dfrac{\sin(t)}{t} < 1$.
So $-1 < 2 - 501 t < 1$, i.e. $\dfrac{1}{501} < t < \dfrac{1}{167}$.
With $t$ this close to $0$, $\sin(t)/t$ is close to $1$, so in fact $t \approx \frac{1}{501}$.  In fact we have 
$1 > \sin(t)/t > 1 - t^2/6$, so $$\dfrac{1}{501} < t < 1503 - \sqrt{2259003}$$
and thus
$$501 > x > \dfrac{1}{1503 - \sqrt{2259003}} = 500.9996673\ldots$$
In particular, your answer $501$ is within the required accuracy.

Comment: Could you kindly explain how $\sqrt{2259003}$ was calculated?

Comment: Solving the quadratic $2 - 501 t = 1 - t^2/6$.